# Full Width Webview iOS issue

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, webview

I'm generating IOS app (Wordpress Website) using Xcode swift. 
here is my ViewContorller.swift code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


        let url = NSURL (string: "http://domainname.com")
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

        webView.loadRequest(request)
```

But the problem is the app has a fixed size, so in some screens the web view is larger than the screen, and in the big screens the webview is smaller.

How to handle this issue? i need the app to look 100% width in all screens.

Please keep in mind that this is my first time working with XCode, getting the app to work is excellent for me so far, so be patient.

Comment: Did you apply layout constraints ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `top,bottom,leading and trailing` constraints to your webview so it will displayed in full screen. This is the issue of `autolayout`.

If you are totally unaware of `autolayout` then you can refer tutorials like [Raywenderlich's tutorial!!](https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2)

Comment: i don't know why i dont see the bottom small menu ( Align, Pin , etc..) in my current project, when i start a new project i can see this menu, how to show it in my current project ?

Comment: go to `file inspector` and make sure that `autolayout` is checked